API endpoint for populating attributes on Sitecore Search
I want to populate the list of attributes and its properties to Sitecore Search. Since I’ve large number of attributes thinking of creating/ leveraging the API endpoint which would programmatically populate the attributes from a JSON file.
As far as I explored I couldn’t find anything related to it. If someone has any idea or experience in creating custom API for Sitecore search your inputs will really help for me. Thanks.

Just to understand you are trying to index the huge list of data into Sitecore search right? Did you try with parallelism (workers) and request extractor for pagination, if the API URL provides data using page numbers?

It sounds like you have a large data set and you are looking at how you would pass that data to sitecore search.
The first thing you will need to do is define the structure of your data inside the sitecore search console.
With that complete, there are a number of ways to get data uploaded. There are two methods that seem most relevant to your situation.
The first (as you mention) is to make your data available via an API. Then inside then consider an API crawler. When configuring this, you define the endpoint, triggers and also exactly how the data in your api maps to the defined model (you do this with something called a document extractor).
Examples of all the above can be seen here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/search/en/users/search-user-guide/configure-an-api-crawler.html
With this method, your crawler will crawler the api periodically and ingest new info as it becomes available.
An alternative approach you might consider is to use the Ingestion API.
With this method, you can setup a one time ingest (or arrange for updates to be made as part of some process). You then send PUT/POST/DELETE requests to the ingestion api for every record in your data set.
By doing this for every record in your data set, your data can be fully ingested into sitecore search.
More information on this can be found d here: https://doc.sitecore.com/search/en/developers/ingestion-api/index.html
